# Altium - Repeated block

Tags: altium

I've a PCB with repeated blocks. I made the design using rooms and coping from the source room to all the others. All work fine, from the the schematic using herarchical block to PCB. There is only a one thing I don't understand: is it possible to modify something in the master room (i.e. changing routing) and then have all the other rooms updated at once without re-copy and past them one by one?

I'm using Altium Designer 10. I attach some pictures of the Rooms tools I can use.

[image: Room Menu]
This is what I can choose from room menu.

[image: past options]
This is what I can configure when I past a copy of a room.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to he question above can be achieved in this way:

Follow this step-by-step [guide](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Creating+a+Multi-channel+Design).

Then you have to create a channel class in which include all your channel. To do that go to Design->Classes and put all your channel in your channel class (in the example below cahnnel class=IN and members INA, INB etc..)
[image: design channel classes]
The when you copy a room format you can find now your brand new channel class. Select all the channel or only those you want to be copied and you're done. All changes will be applied at once to all channel selcted!
[image: confirm channel format]

Comment: I suspect that if you've had to add things manually to a channel class there must be something slightly unusual about the schematic.  In the schematic, are all the channels separate sheet blocks, or is it a single multi-channel block?

Comment: It is a single multichannel block

Comment: I've to say that channel class was already present and correctly imported from schematic but was empty. So the only manual operation I made was to insert class members.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Use Design->Rooms->Copy Room Formats.

It's described in this [document](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Creating+a+Multi-channel+Design).

Comment: Thanks. I've update my post with some pics..maybe helps to understand better if my version of Altium can do that.

Comment: Got it!! it is necessary to add all rooms in a channel class and then apply the changes to the whole class. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I've embellished it a bit now...

Comment: Yes, but in that document they didn't explain how to do what i described abow. @David it was told me not to answer my own post...but ok i'll put an aswer with the solution ;)